# A projective resolution for $R = k[x,y,z]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R = k[x,y,z]$ where $k$ is considered as an $R$-module. I need to write down a projective resolution for $k$.

What I already do not understand: how is the $R$-module structure on $k$ defined in this case?

We learned projective resolutions as sequences $$ \ldots \rightarrow P_2 \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0 $$ where all the $P_j$ are projective objects.

In categorical terms, we defined a projective object $P$ as an object such that for any arrow $f : P \rightarrow X$ and any epimorphisms $e : Y \rightarrow X$, there exists a unique factorization $f = e \circ f^{'}$.

But I'm complete at loss of how to use this definition here. How does one solve these kind of problems? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Never mind the old comment. You can find a free resolution in terms of $R$, by first taking the map $\varepsilon: R \rightarrow k$ sending the variables to $0$. The kernel of this map is isomorphic to $R^3$, which determines the next step in the resolution. Then you continue constructing maps $d_i$ such that $d_i \circ d_{i-1} = 0$.

Comment: If someone gave you this problem without telling you how the $R$-module structure on $k$ is defined, then that's their fault.  Ask them what they had in mind.  (Probably they meant the $R$-module structure where $x,y,$ and $z$ all act as $0$, but that's not the only possible $R$-module structure.)